# How to use angular2 retrieved data as html tag?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am reading a json file in angular2.
so far I am able to get the data from json file.I have created few angular2 components in project who has selectors in this data.
I want to load all my components using this data as html tag.
i.e. If I am getting `col.uiComponent="HEADING"`,then I want to use this as

```
<HEADING></HEADING>
```

so,I need to do this as

`<col.uiComponent> Loading.. </col.uiComponent>`

I tried using this code:

```
<div *ngFor="#srColumn of sRow.secRowColumns">                        
   <{{srColumn.uiComponent}}>Loading </{{srColumn.uiComponent}}>                       
</div>
```

**Child Component**

```
@Component({
selector: 'DYNAMIC-BODY-1',    
templateUrl: 'app/DYNAMIC-BODY-1/DYNAMIC-BODY-1.component.html'   
})
```

**DYNAMIC-BODY-1.component.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 divDynamic">
    <table  style="width:100%;">
        <tr style="background-color:#B8B8B8">
            <th>{{comp.data}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
</div>
```

using DynamicComponentLoader I did this.

```
constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, injector: Injector,private dataService: DataService) {
    dcl.loadAsRoot(DynamicBody1Component, 'DYNAMIC-BODY-1', injector);
 }
```

my child component has selector "DYNAMIC-BODY-1"
Its Showing me error like:

```
EXCEPTION: The selector "DYNAMIC-BODY-1" did not match any elements
```

Plz Help.

Comment: Please also add the template HTML of the component that contains the `<DYNAMIC-BODY-1></DYNAMIC-BODY-1>` tag.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer..I have provided all the code now .

Comment: Adding HTML this way is not supported (only plain text). To add HTML use `<th [innerHTML]="comp.data"></th>` instead.

Comment: no use..same error again.I am thinking this might be because my parent component is not getting child components selector  @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: I guess you need to move the `dcl.loadAsRoot...` code to `ngAfterViewInit()` for Angular to have time to build the view before you try to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work. You can't add components/directives dynamically with dynamic binding.

Angular has [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) for this to add components imperatively

See also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular2%5D+dynamiccomponentloader

Comment: can you provide few more details about how to use this dynamicComponentLoader .I tried to integrate it into my code..but its not working

Comment: EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ParserComponent'(?, ?, DataService). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'ParserComponent' is decorated with Injectable.

Comment: I tried this:  `constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, injector: Injector,private dataService: DataService) {
        dcl.loadAsRoot(DynamicBody1Component, '#ICICI-DYNAMIC-BODY-1', injector);
     }`

Comment: Did you import `DynamicComponentLoader` and `Injector`?

Comment: @gunter..its showing me this error now. `EXCEPTION: The selector "DYNAMIC-BODY-1" did not match any elements` ,my child component has selector `"DYNAMIC-BODY-1"`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.